# How to refer to the array element in a link response?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I want to return a list of elements, by only providing the IDs. Then I want to tell the user that they can retrieve the individual details by calling the get element api.
Problem is I'm not sure about the syntax, can you check this out?

```
paths:
 /pet:
get:
  summary: Get all pets
  description: Returns the list of all pets
  operationId: getAllPets
  tags:
    - pet
  parameters:
    - name: full
      in: query
      description: whatever return all or part
      required: false
      schema:
        type: boolean
  responses:
    '200':
      description: The list of all pets in the store, can be full or only first level with partials
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      links:
        getPetDetails:
          description: in case of partial you can use this operation to retrieve individual pet details
          operationId: getPetById
          parameters:
            petId: '$response.body#/id' #...but the response body is an array!
```